# Orthogonal projections question

Tags: matrix, projection

I'm very VERY new into the game development world and I had just some slight trouble wrapping my head around something.  We were told between classes just to think about how scaling matrices can perform simple orthogonal projections on a cardinal axis or plane.

What I know is orthogonal projections are 3D objects minus the z-coordinates in most cases.  Scaling matrices are a matter of altering x,y,z coordinates to adjust the shape of an object.  So, the only way for scaling to actually make a orthogonal projection is for the x,y,or z to be scaled by a factor of zero.  Am I kinda getting it so far or is there still a lot going over my head?

Answer (score 1):

An orthographic projection is better described as a kind of parallel projection, because if you were to draw lines between the points in "world space" (ie 3d) to "projected space" (ie 2d) they would be parallel to each other.

All projections map one space to another, though for the most part when we're talking about orthographic projections we're transforming a cloud to be coincident to a plane (the screen).

You could open a 3d modelling program and then simulate orthographic projection for any angle by first rotating a mesh into position, then scaling it by zero along the z axis. The vertices of the model will end up being coincident to the xy plane. There's a little more to it in practice, of course, since any triangles with normals parallel to the -z axis line would end up [z-fighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).